# Ошибка в коде PHP

Tags: php, sql, mysql

Здравствуйте! Вот эта ошибка выходит в админке сайта:

```
Warning: mysql_result() [function.mysql-result]: Unable to jump to row 0 on MySQL result index 8 in /home/httpd/vhosts/адресс-сайта/httpdocs/admin_tools/mails/config_mails.php on line 37
```

Это сам запрос в (этом файле `admin_tools/mails/config_mails.php`)

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT `price` FROM `tb_config` WHERE `item`='cena_mails' AND `howmany`='1'");
$cena_mails_1 = mysql_result($sql,0,0);
```

Где может быть ошибка? Таких одинаковых ошибок очень много, только ругается на разные файлы.

Comment: очень похоже на то, что у вас результат выполнения mysql_query нулевой, сделайте вывод $sql.

Comment: попробуйте вывести количество полученных результатов.

Answer (score 1):

Ну тебе ответили, что скорее всего пустой результат.
Если непонятно как сделать то примерно так.

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT `price` FROM `tb_config` WHERE `item`='cena_mails' AND `howmany`='1'");
if (mysql_num_rows($sql)>0){
    $cena_mails_1 = mysql_result($sql);
}
```